# Scala sealed abstract class with enum object matching against string

Tags: scala

I am a beginner in scala, I have a case class for the response I am getting as `json payload`

```
case class CallbackPayload(
            automation_id: String,
            business_key: String,
            state: String #received , validating
       )
```

I have a sealed abstract class

```
object ExecutionStatus {
  sealed abstract class ExecutionState(status: String) {
    override def toString: String = status
  }

  case object RECEIVED extends ExecutionState("received")
  case object VALIDATING extends ExecutionState("validating")
}
```

Now based on the `response payload state` I want to do a match against the `ExecutionStatus` `objects`

Something like below

```
def callback(payload: CallbackPayload): Either[Throwable, Json] = {
    payload.state match {
      case VALIDATING => Right(Json.obj("status" -> Json.fromString("validating")))
    .....
    }
  }
```

Now because of payload.state type string I am unable to . How to do that in scala.

Comment: Why not just match `payload.state`?

Comment: Yeah there was a typo , I am matching `payload.state` only. But I want to match against the `object` not `string`

Comment: I am not sure , is there a way I can transform that `payload.state` to `ExecutionState object`

Comment: you can use scala 3 enum for ExecutionStatus, cf https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UqL4wclzRdS5ioK96VJWbA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may want to match on the `status` string, like so (using a simplified model of your code):

```
object ExecutionStatus {
  sealed abstract class ExecutionState(val status: String) {
    override def toString: String = status
  }    

  case object RECEIVED extends ExecutionState("received")
  case object VALIDATING extends ExecutionState("validating")
}

def parse(state: String): Either[Throwable, Map[String, String]] = {
  state match {
    case ExecutionStatus.RECEIVED.status =>
      Right(Map("status" -> "received"))
    case ExecutionStatus.VALIDATING.status =>
      Right(Map("status" -> "validating"))
    case _ => 
      Left(new IllegalArgumentException(s"unrecognized state $state"))
  }
}

assert(parse("received") == Right(Map("status" -> "received")))
assert(parse("validating") == Right(Map("status" -> "validating")))
assert(parse("foo").isLeft)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/OlEfJqQZTreQT8jpRpQogQ/8).

Notice that in order to do so I had to make `status` a `val` so that it's public (without it, `status` is only a constructor parameter).

Comment: Nice , I was really struggling making it work without support of transformation functions . Thanks for showing the way.